# send a CTRL-C over a network

Tags: c++, telnet

I want to replicate a condition where in if I did a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> after I connecting to a server using telnet, the server would crash. I want to write a C++ program which does it. What does telnet send over the network when we do a <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> . I read that <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> is '0x03'. Does it send the same thing or does it send something else and how should I send it using a C++ application.

Comment: Why not use Wireshark to trace what is really sent to make your server crash? That way you won't have to guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Telnet really does send 0x03.  Telnet is just a regular TCP connection with some escape codes that do various things.

But to test a server over telnet, you probably really want to use the "Expect" utility:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect